# Explanation about Heatmap and dendrogram in R

Tags: r, heatmap, dendrogram

I'm new to R and Data Analysis. I`m doing a coursera course on DataScience. At the moment I am stuck with clustering, Heatmap and dendrogram. I know how to create a heatmap and a dendrogram. But I cannot find any expanation about the connection of the two. When I do the command in R :

```
heatmap(dataMatrix)
```

I get a Heatmap and on the left and upper side of this heatmap I get 2 dendrograms. Also all my row-numbers and column-numbers are in strange orders.

**Can anyone explain to me what that means?**

**Does anybody know a tutorial about that?**

Thank you

[image]

Comment: can you post a screen shot of the graphs?

Comment: I think you need to start reading about  hierarchical clustering. Anyway is not a question for here. Maybe you can try at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), but I think is too basic even for that